# Salvar número em agenda telefonica?

Tags: javascript, html5, mobile

tenho uma mobile app acessando via browser, nesta tem um botão com número telefônico. Gostaria que quando o usuário clica se neste botão o número fosse salvo na agenda telefônica.

Obrigado

Comment: Podes ser mais claro? estás a fazer ou fizeste uma APP que tem funcionalidade de browser e quando clicar num numero de telefone ele guardar nos contactos?

Comment: Sergio e uma mobile app, acessando pelo browser. Existe um botão com o numero telefônico, quando o usuário clicar neste número ele salva na agenda telefonica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto não é possível, até por questão de segurança. Suponha que fosse possível - neste caso, uma página poderia sobrescrever os contatos do usuário.

Por outro lado, você pode transformar um número de telefone em um link. Neste caso, o usuário poderá clicar no link que o telefone aparecerá no aplicativo de ligações. Basta usar algo como:

```
<a href="tel:+55 99 10101010">Número de telefone</a>
```

<sup><sub>Teste aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/ycmyu86b/</sub></sup>

Com o número no aplicativo de telefone, o usuário pode então adicioná-lo aos contatos, ou ligar para o número. Mas a decisão do que fazer sempre ficará com o usuário.

**EDITADO**: @Sergio fez um comentário interessante, sugerindo utilizar vCards. Embora o contato não vá ser adicionado automaticamente, o vCard realmente tem muitas vantagens: dá para sugerir o nome do contato, adicionar mais informações etc. E é possível fazê-lo sem sequer precisar de servidor! Considere o vCard abaixo:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N: brandizzi
FN: brandizzi
TEL;WORK;VOICE: +55 (66) 7788 9910
END:VCARD
```

Podemos codificá-lo para pô-lo em uma URL (por exemplo, com `encodeURI()`):

```
"BEGIN:VCARD%0AVERSION:2.1%0AN:%20brandizzi%0AFN:%20brandizzi%0ATEL;WORK;VOICE:%20+55%20(66)%207788%209910%0AEND:VCARD"
```

Agora, basta usar essa versão codificada em uma URL de dados

```
<a 
  href="data:text/vcard,BEGIN:VCARD%0AVERSION:2.1%0AN:%20brandizzi%0AFN:%20brandizzi%0ATEL;WORK;VOICE:%20+55%20(66)%207788%209910%0AEND:VCARD"
  download="meucontato.vcf">
    Link para contato
</a>
```

Pessoalmente, gosto da URL para o telefone porque eu, como usuário, quase nunca quero adicionar um contato à minha agenda, quero só ligar. Agora, suspeito que o vCard funciona melhor para o que o OP quer.

Comment: Mas não seria possivel fazer a webapp retornar um download de um `vcf` ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1773876/2256325

Comment: Obrigado @brandizzi o `<a href="">` ajuda.

Comment: @Sergio é possível, mas novamente o usuário terá de escolher se vai ou não adicionar o contato. Não é possível fazê-lo automaticamente via script. Por outro lado, o vCard realmente tem uma vantagem: é possível passar mais informações através dele, além do número. Nem é necessário gerar no servidor, dá para fazer via JavaScript. Ao menos eu consegui fazer, num teste aqui. Vou complementar a minha resposta.

Comment: @brandizzi se tiveres tempo para um exemplo com vCard seria excelente. Entretanto parece que a tua ajuda já resolveu o problema :)